creating a 2D numpy array from the min of the i-th and j-th elements of a 1D array
Given a 1D array, I would like to create a 2D numpy array where the element at arr2d[i,j] is equal to min(arr1d[i], arr1d[j]).
I can achieve this with the code below:
arr1d = np.array([5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3])
arr2d = np.zeros((arr1d.shape[0], arr1d.shape[0]))
for i in range(arr1d.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr1d.shape[0]):
        arr2d[i, j] = min(arr1d[i], arr1d[j])

...but I feel like there should be a more idiomatic and/or efficient way to achieve this with numpy. Can anyone suggest a cleaner solution?

Maybe: np.minimum.outer(arr1d, arr1d)

@Chrysophylaxs I wasn't familiar with ufunc.outer, but that is exactly what is being done here (the documentation essentially show OP's code). Post this as an answer?

yes - np.minimum.outer(arr1d, arr1d) is exactly what I'm looking for - Thanks @Chrysophylaxs!

Imagine you repeated arr1d to make a square array. Then, arr2d is the elementwise minimum of that square array and its transpose (since that will compare i with j).
a1 = np.repeat(arr1d[None,:], arr1d.shape[0], axis=0)
a2 = a1.T
arr2d = np.minimum(a1, a2)  # elementwise minimum

Here is what a1 looks like:
array([[5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3],
       [5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3],
       [5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3],
       [5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3],
       [5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3],
       [5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3]])

And here's arr2d:
array([[5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3],
       [4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3],
       [4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3]])

Or, without the intermediate arrays (as suggested in the comments):
arr2d = np.minimum(arr1d, arr1d[:,None])


if you are using minimum then do np.minimum(arr1d, arr1d[:,None]) or use the outer ufunc as given in the comments

Thank you for the breakdown - very helpful. I've accepted this as the answer in the absence of Chrysophylaxs posting his answer.
